# Reg Exp: match numbers and spaces only

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a js script to validate a form field and I need to check it contains only numbers and possibly whitespace.

What is the regular expression for that?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 9):

You can try something like

```
var isSpacedNumber = (/^\s*\d+\s*$/i).test(<string value>);
```

The regular expression consists of the parts

- "^" saying that match should start from beginning of input
- \s* meaning zero or more (*) whitespaces (\s)
- \d+ meaning one or more (+) digits (\d)
- \s* meaning zero or more (*) whitespaces (\s)
- $ meaning match end of string

Without ^ and $ the regular expression would capture any number in a string, and thus "number is 123" would give positive indication.

[More information about javascript regular expression can be found here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Answer (score 4):

```
var str = "Watch out for the rock!".match(/^[\d\s]+$/g)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `\d` character matches any digit which is the same as using `[0-9]`, the `\s` character matches any whitespace.

To check if a string is a number (assuming there are no dots or comma's):

```
var regex = /^[\d]+$/;
```

However, an easier method for you would be to use the `isNaN()` function. If the function returns true, the number is illegal (`NaN`). If it returns false, it's a correct number.

```
if( !isNaN( value ) ) {
     // The value is a correct number
} else {
     // The value is not a correct number
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this regular expression:

```
/^[\d\s]+$/
```