# How to validate whether an input field only has numbers (but allow spaces)?

Tags: jquery

I have created a small jQuery code to validate if an input field only has numbers:

```
var $contactno = $('#contactno');

$('.status').hide();

$('.js-validator').click(function() {

    if ($contactno.val().length < 1) {

        $('.status').show().text("Please enter a value.");

    } else {

        if (isNaN($contactno.val()) == true) {

            // Show below as .status
            $('.status').show().text("Contact number must be a numeric value (0 - 9).");

        } else {

            $('.status').show().text("Contact number is valid!");

        }
    }

});
```

However, if there's a space in the input e.g. 3644 5354, the input becomes invalid, which shouldn't be the case. It should still be valid.

How do I fix this?

Comment: try:
`isNaN($contactno.val().replace(' ',''))` in your condition

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209898/reg-exp-match-numbers-and-spaces-only

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var regex_userId = /^[0-9\\ ]{2,50}$/;
            var $contactno = $('#contactno');

            $('.status').hide();

            $('#btn_click').click(function() {

                if ($contactno.val().length < 1) {

                    $('.status').show().text("Please enter a value.");

                } else {



                    if (regex_userId.test($contactno.val())) {

                        // Show below as .status
                        $('.status').show().text("valid");

                    } else {

                        $('.status').show().text("Contact number must be a numeric value (0 - 9).");

                    }
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <h3 class='status'></h3>
    <input type='text' id='contactno' />
    <button class='js-validator' id='btn_click'>click</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Please check with regular expression to check such validations